# Java Generics - Comparable interface

Tags: java, generics, comparable

In the code below `Comparable` interface is used to ensure x and y should be of same reference type but as V is extending T so V should be of the same type as T or subclass of T then what is the point of using `Comparable` interface.
Also if I am not using `Comparable` interface then the last call to `isIf` method is getting compile despite x and y are of different types.
Can anyone explain the use `Comparable` interface regarding this program?

```
public class Generics_13 {

    static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean isIn(T x, V[] y) {
        for(int i = 0;i < y.length;i++) 
            if(x.equals(y[i])) return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer nums[] = {10, 20, 30};

        if(isIn(10, nums))
            System.out.println("10 belongs to the array");
        if(!isIn(60, nums))
            System.out.println("70 doesnt belong to the array");

        String arr[] = {"Neeraj", "Parth", "Ritum"};
        if(!isIn("abc", arr))
            System.out.println("abc doesnt belongs to the array");

        /*if(isIn("String", nums))      //  illegal
            System.out.println("This wont compile");
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: `Object.equals` doesn't require an `Comparable` so why ? What do you want to do with `T` ? Also, you could use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) instead.

Comment: Place the brackets right behind the data types, instead of behind the variable names, by convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current use of generics doesn't really makes sense, because no method from `Comparable` is ever used, which means that you could simply remove the `extends` declaration.

Also the Type `V` is also not used, as you can simply replace it by `T` and not break your logic. so the final result would look like this:

```
public class Generics_13 {
    static <T> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y) {
        for(int i = 0;i < y.length;i++) 
           if(x.equals(y[i])) return true;

        return false;
    }

    // main() etc follow here
}
```

But now that we have the `Stream API` in `java-8` you can use the following snippet to achieve the same thing:

```
static <T> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y) {
    return Arrays.stream(y).anyMatch(i -> i.equals(x));
}
```

Comment: I was going through a Java book and I was stuck at this program. Thanks, for answering though.

Answer (score 3):

The comparable here in your scenario is optional.

```
T extends Comparable<T>
```

What this means is that whatever value you are passing should implement the interface comparable. 
which basically means that the type parameter can be compared with other instances of the same type.

Now you might be wondering that since you are passing primitive data types, then how does the code not throw an error?
The reason for this is that the primitives are autoboxed to wrapper objects which implement Comparable. 
So your ints become Integer and String is already an object both of which implement Comparable.

PS : your code will also work for objects provided that the class implements comparable

Comment: I am aware of the autoboxing happening in this program. What I wanted to know was that as V extends T here so y should be of the same datatype as T or subclass of T but I am not getting any error in the last call of isIn method where y is Integer type and x is String type.

Comment: they are both Strings in your example. you are referring to this right if(!isIn("abc", arr)) ?

Comment: No, I`m talking about the last if structure which I wrote as comments.

Comment: are you sure you are not getting any error? that is highly unlikely. With that line the program won't compile.

Comment: If I'm not using Comparable interface then I`m not getting any errors.

Comment: @a_petrolhead that is because the type `T` resolves to `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>`. Which both `Integer` and `String` implement

Comment: This is all actually correct, but it doesn’t address the question of why the method is using Comparable.

Comment: @Lino Actually, I wanted to ask the other way around.If I don't use `Comparable` here then since `V` extends `T` so `V` should be of the same datatype as `T` or subclass of T but the `last if structure which is commented` would work fine despite `String` and `Integer` are different data types. Can you enlight me about this?

Comment: @Lino I got your point. I just went through the java docs. Thanks very much.